# C++ sleep pthread conflict

Tags: c++, eclipse, pthreads, mutex, sleep

I am writing a code about the deadlocks and their detection, i use eclipse Juno C/C++ on Ubuntu 12.10, 64 bit.
The problem is when i use

> sleep(1)

, i get this

> sleep was not declared in this scope

when i build the project, i tried to include

> include < unistd.h>

, but then all the pthread functions like

> pthread_join

gives me errors like

> undefined reference to pthread_join

, without **#include < unistd.h>** such error doesn't show up.

sample code:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <semaphore.h>
#include <queue>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace std;

pthread_mutex_t mutex;
sem_t sem; //used for writing in the console

.......

void cross(Batman b) {
// code to check traffic from the right, use counters, condition
sem_wait(&sem);
cout << "BAT " << b.num << " from " << b.direction << " crossing" << endl;
sem_post(&sem);
sleep(1);
}
........
```

p.s. i followed these instructions to get pthreads working in other project and i did the same for this project 
http://blog.asteriosk.gr/2009/02/15/adding-pthread-to-eclipse-for-using-posix-threads/

p.s. i am working on this project with a friend and i used the same code he uses and still get those errors, while he doesn't

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you `#include < unistd.h>`, you fixed sleep function look up issue, now you have pthread library issue.

Next you need to `#include <pthread.h>` and link your application with pthread library

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you have two different errors,

first `sleep()` is undefined because you forgot to include unistd.h. I'd also include pthread.h but it sounds like it might get pulled in by one of the headers you include.

Secondly it sounds like you have a linker error add, you can either compile with -pthread or add -lpthread to the linker. The reason it doesn't show up is because linking can only be done once the files have been compiled and the first error is blocking this. I'd bet that ld doesn't like -pthread for some reason (have you installed libpthread-dev?). You can try changing -pthread to -lpthread.